# Displaying Clover Historical Trend in Hudson

Tags: hudson, clover

Right now, my Hudson job runs Clover to carry out it's code coverage analysis.

I'd like to be able to display the Clover historical trend graph as part of the job - like Hudson displays the Unit Test Trend, Checkstyle trend etc etc.

Are there any thoughts as to how I could get my historical data into the dashboard of my job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/%20Sonar) instead. Found it very easy to set-up, and it's Time Machine functionality did what I wanted this to do. Case closed!